# checker-framework incompatible types in type argument

Tags: java, checker-framework

I have some code like this where I store a map to java threadlocal,

```
import java.util.*;

class Foo {
  private final ThreadLocal<Map<String, String>> barMap = ThreadLocal.withInitial(HashMap::new);
}
```

when enabling the nullness check from checkerframework I get

```
Error: [type.argument.type.incompatible] incompatible types in type argument.
   found   : @Initialized @NonNull Map<@Initialized @NonNull String, @Initialized @NonNull String>
   required: [extends @Initialized @Nullable Object super null]
```

I don't understand how to resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://github.com/typetools/checker-framework/issues/979) in the Checker Framework.  You should suppress the warning.

The Checker Framework currently uses the Java 7 type inference algorithm.  Java 8 made a major change to type inference, which requires a re-implementation in the Checker Framework.  (The Checker Framework is essentially a compiler in its own right.)  That re-implementation is partly done, but has not yet been completed.